# I am getting an error while trying to create an user using Express NodeJs and Passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, backend, registration

I am trying to create a user registration page, but when i tries to make a post request to save the user in the db, i get an error that error `TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function` Also i use this `npm install --save express-validator`

`app.js the Main file`

```
 const express = require('express');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express(); //main app variable that represents the application

const morgan = require('morgan');

const bodyparser = require("body-parser"); //requiring the body parser         

const path = require('path');

const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs');
```

`the controller PostRequest call Back function`

```
    exports.createUserForm = (req, res, next) => {

    //return to the list
    //res.redirect('/all-users');

    console.log('Post CREATE CATEGORY /create-user');

    // getting the request body

    const username = req.body.username;

    const password = req.body.password;

    const password2 = req.body.password2;


    // check the body request by using express validator

    req.checkBody('username', 'UserName is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'UserName is required').equals(req.body.password);

    // get the error if there are any 

    let errors = req.validationErrors();

    // check then 

    if (errors) {
        res.render('./register', {
            errors: errors
        });
    } else {
        let newUser = new userSchema({

            username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
            password: password
        });
    }

    //hash the user's password before we save the user

    bycrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {

        bycrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                //ERROR PAGE
                console.log(err);
            }

            /// Hashing the password
            newUser.password = hash;

            /// saving the user

            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                } else {
                    req.flash('success', 'You successfully registered')
                    req.redirect('/halalMunchies/login');
                }
            })
        })
    })




}
```

`The Error in the log`

```
TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
at exports.createUserForm (E:\HalalMunchies\server\controller\usersController.js:36:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (E:\HalalMunchies\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in app.js

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(expressValidator())
```

Comment: I added this and i got this app crashed in the log >> `at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Answer (score 0):

you can move your validation to a separate file like `userValidation.js`:

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = function handle() {
    return [
        check('username').notEmpty().withMessage('UserName is required'),
        check('password').notEmpty().withMessage('Password is required')
    ]
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
app.post('/user/register',
    userValidation.handle(),
    userController.register
);
```

Comment: coz my call back function is in a separated js file, where i should add this part `const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
` I tried to put it in the callBack function controller but no change happened, i am still getting the same error.

Comment: i just edited my answer, give it a go @HeshamEldawy

Comment: thanks so much Sin, i solved by using version 5 of validator, but after that i faced another problem, plz if u got time can u take a look at it. I appreciate your help. thnx in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69891444/15454800

Comment: you're very welcome, i'm not very experienced with express validator ether. but if it keeps troubling you, i highly recommend using yup: [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup)
it much easier to understand and use and its more flexible too @HeshamEldawy