# When i try to create a new user, the Post request doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, frontend, passport.js, backend

in the Post request :

1. i try to get the body request
2. check the body request by using express validator
3. get the error if there are any
4. if error >> reload create_user page and print in the console the error >> here it gives me in the log this `{ location: 'body', param: 'username', msg: 'UserName is required', value: undefined },`
5. Else will create a new user object from the module schema and use bycrypt and hash the password
6. Then it will save the newUser object and if there's an error will `console.log` otherwise redirect to the login page.

`app.js file` the rootFile

```
    const express = require('express');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express(); //main app variable that represents the application

const morgan = require('morgan');

const bodyparser = require("body-parser"); //requiring the body parser         

const path = require('path');

const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

const bycrypt = require('bcryptjs');

app.use(expressValidator())
          
//require the monogo db file

const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');

dotenv.config({ path: 'config.env' });

//for the port variable
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//requiring morgan file 
//to log the request 
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// mongo db connection 

connectDB();

//to show >> req.body
app.use(bodyparser.json());
//app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

`createUserForm` POST REQUEST CALLBACK FUNCTION

```js
exports.createUserForm = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Post CREATE CATEGORY /create-user');
  // getting the request body
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const password2 = req.body.password2;
  // check the body request by using express validator
  req.checkBody('username', 'UserName is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'UserName is required').equals(req.body.password);
  // get the error if there are any 
  let errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    //if there is an error so rerinder the templet
    res.render('users/create_user.ejs', {
      errors: errors //pass along the errors
    }, console.log(errors));
  } else {
    let newUser = new userSchema({
      username: username, // first is the attribute NAME of the model , second is the name value tag in the html file
      password: password
    });
    bycrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      bycrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
          //ERROR PAGE
          console.log(err);
        }
        /// Hashing the password
        newUser.password = hash;
        /// saving the user
        newUser.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success', 'You successfully registered')
            res.redirect('/halalMunchies/login');
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
};
```

the form in the ejs file:

```html
<form action="/halalMunchies/create-user" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="username"> Username </label>
    <input id="username" class="form-control" name="username" required autofocus="autofocus" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password"> Password </label> <input id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required autofocus="autofocus" type="password" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password2"> confirm Password </label> <input id="password2" class="form-control" name="password2" required autofocus="autofocus" type="password" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add User</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I submit it reloads the form page and nothing happened in the database. Basically it just stops at this part...

```js
if (errors) {
  //if there is an error so rerinder the templet
  res.render('users/create_user.ejs', {
    errors: errors //pass along the errors
  }, console.log(errors));
```

Comment: Don't pass `console.log(errors)` as the `callback` parameter to [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render). If you want to see the errors in your HTML, you'd need to include them in your `.ejs` template

Comment: Okay I took out the console.log(errors) and the error still exist

Comment: Have you added in the required body-parsing middleware? Ie [`app.use(express.urlencoded())`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded)

Comment: i have this `app.use(express.urlencoded())` in my app.js file but not in the function controller file that holds the call back functions

Answer (score 0):

**You get your undefined body response, you may forget to include a body-parsing middleware.**

Add this in `app.js` `(server.js)` or your root file of the app

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

It parses your request and you get all values...

Comment: nothing has been changed, still the problem exists